# np.where not working as expected in pandas groupby/apply function

Tags: pandas, numpy, group-by

I use an `np.where()` statement to define a Pandas column. It works perfectly fine outside of a Pandas groupby/apply function, but seems to fail inside of the groupby/apply function.

Here's original dataframe:

```
unit of measure | city
---------------   ---------
NaN             | 'Atlanta'
'SF'            | 'Phoenix'
'Acre'          | 'Los Angeles'
```

Here's the np.where() statement:

```
testing['regex_unit'] = np.where(testing['unit of measure'].notna(),
                                testing['unit of measure'].str.lower(),
                                testing['city'])
```

Result (outside of groupby/apply):

```
unit of measure | city          | regex_unit
---------------   -------------   ----------
Nan             | 'Atlanta'     | 'Atlanta'
'SF'            | 'Phoenix'     | 'sf'
'Acre'          | 'Los Angeles' | 'acre'
```

But when I group by 'city' and run the np.where() inside of an apply function...

```
def apply_function(df):
    
    # Make all string columns title case
    for col in df.columns:
        if (df[col].dtype == 'object'):
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).title())

    # Replace string "Nans" with NaN
    df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)
        
    # Replace 'No Zoning Data Available' with NaN
    df = df.replace('No Zoning Data Available', np.nan)

    # Double check the dataframe and column dtype
    display(df)
    print(df['unit of measure'].iloc[0])
    print(df['unit of measure'].isnull())

    df['regex_unit'] = np.where(df['unit of measure'].notna(),
                                df['unit of measure'].str.lower(),
                                df['city'])
    return df

new_df = testing.groupby(['city'], as_index=False).apply(apply_function)
```

I get this error...

```
unit of measure | city
---------------   ---------
NaN             | 'Atlanta'

nan
0    True
Name: unit of measure, dtype: bool

     2     df['regex_unit'] = np.where(df['unit of measure'].notna(),
---> 3                                 df['unit of measure'].str.lower(),
     4                                 df['regex_unit_temp'])

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Why is np.where() acting different inside of the function applied to a groupby dataframe? What am I not seeing or understanding?

**EDIT:** When I comment out `df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)`, everything works.

I added print statements just before the np.where() statement to show that it is indeed a null value, and therefore should apply the 2nd logic (df['regex_unit_temp']), not the first (df['unit of measure'].str.lower()).

What am I not understanding about how `df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)` is used in this function?

Comment: What 'df.dtypes' gives you?

Comment: your code works fine for me, try `df['unit of measure'].astype(str).str.lower()`

Comment: The code works for me too (Pandas == 1.4.1)

Comment: For me working well.

Comment: btw,, what is reason for call code per groups or in apply?

Comment: ^ You guys are right, the original code worked. I updated the question to include more of the function. It appears the `df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)` part of the function is messing with the np.where() statement, even though the print statement demonstrates it's still a null value.

Comment: @jezrael I have a large dataframe with thousands of cities and with duplicates of cities with different unit of measures. So I group by city and then apply the np.where to the unit of measure (as each city normally has at least 2 rows). The "Atlanta" example is a simple one with only one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the root problem, although I lack understanding of **why** it causes a problem, so any thoughts or further explanation would be appreciated.

The problem is with this line being used in the np.where() statement:

```
df['unit of measure'].str.lower()
```

The np.where() statement works correctly if changed to this:

```
df['regex_unit'] = np.where(df['unit of measure'].notna(),
                                True,
                                False)
```

And works correctly if changed to this:

```
df['regex_unit'] = np.where(df['unit of measure'].notna(),
                            df['unit of measure'],
                            df['city'])
```

But the problem occurs when we turn `df['unit of measure']` into `df['unit of measure'].str.lower()`.

`df['unit of measure']` returns a series, and `df['unit of measure'].str.lower()` also returns a series. I'm not sure why this would cause a problem if we are only applying the str.lower() method on a cell that is notna(). Again, any further clarification would be appreciated, but for now my question is answered.